# bug when go to production server

Tags: php, symfony

I developed a website using Symfony2 for my studies. Everything works perfect in development, but when I upload all my project on the production server all I have is a blank webpage. I already tried following:

empty cache and logs folder -> nothing,

look at the prod.log after refreshing the page -> empty

look at the apache log, last line is something like ->

```
[Mon Mar 03 22:18:02 2014] [error] [client 192.168.1.10] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Symfony\\Component\\Yaml\\Exception\\ParseException' with message 'Reference "ECEBE99D97B29D1487A9EADB243C76E409A9C84C'" does not exist at line 0.' in /usr/share/portefolio/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Yaml/Parser.php:395\nStack trace:\n#0
```

I don't know why i have this issue but when I try to empty cache by comman line with `php app/console cache:clear --env=prod`
I obtain this error

> [Symfony\Component\Config\Exception\FileLoaderLoadException]
>     Cannot import resource "/usr/share/portefolio/app/config/parameters.yml" from "/usr/share/portefolio/app/config/config.yml". (Reference "ECEBE99D97B29D1487A9EADB243C76E409A9C84C'" does not exist at line 0.)
>
> [Symfony\Component\Yaml\Exception\ParseException]
>     Reference "ECEBE99D97B29D1487A9EADB243C76E409A9C84C'" does not exist at line 0.`

When I went to production, I delete files like `config_dev.yml`, `config_text.yml`, `app_dev.php`, `routing_dev.php`, is this can be the reason why I can't access the website.
Thanks for your help and sorry again for the bad English.

Comment: did you check to see if the website works if you put those files back?

Comment: I only think about that during I was posting my first message, and I can't upload files right now but I will do it as soon as possible and post the result here.

Comment: Try running this and if it worked let me know: `php app/console cache:clear --env=prod --no-debug`

Comment: better yet try `cd /usr/share/portefolio` then `rm -rf vendor` then `php composer.phar install`. Sometimes fresh vendors fix all the problems. Or you could also run `php composer.phar update` if you are ok updating all your vendors.

Comment: try to activate errors on your production server in php.ini, you ll see what blocks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK It's works !!!
I upload all the "dev" files and I had the same FileLoaderLoadException but now I know where was it, the mysql password was written in encrypted format in parameters.yml  so I put it in "not encrypted format" and it's ok, I can access the website.
Thanks to all you.